# PHP: Count same values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to count the same values at the deepest/last level of a multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
[svote001] => Array
    (
        [0] => 006
        [1] => 006
        [2] => 007
    )

[svote002] => Array
    (
        [0] => 000
        [1] => 000
        [2] => 000
    )

[svote003] => Array
    (
        [0] => 002
        [1] => 003
        [2] => 001
    )
)
```

converted to

```
Array
(
[svote001] => Array
    (
        [006] => 2
        [007] => 1
    )

[svote002] => Array
    (
        [000] => 3
    )

[svote003] => Array
    (
        [001] => 1
        [002] => 1
        [003] => 1
    )
)
```

The counted values should additionally be sorted from high to low numbers.

Comment: Is the array always 2-dimensional?

Comment: Yes, the array is always 2-dimensional and all "inner" arrays have the same amount of values: all 3 values or 4 or 5...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = array_count_values($v);
    arsort($result[$k]);
}
```

- Loop through the array (exposing the key) to access each inner array
- Count the values of the inner array (value will be key and count will be value)
- Sort by the values (count) preserving the keys

Answer (score 2):

This should fit your needs:

```
<?php

$a = array(
    'svote001' => array("006", "006", "007"),
    'svote002' => array("000", "000", "000"),
    'svote003' => array("003", "001", "001"),
);
$resultArray = array();

foreach ($a as $arrayName => $arrayData){
    $resultArray[$arrayName] = array();
    foreach ($arrayData as $value){
        if (empty($resultArray[$arrayName][$value])){
            $resultArray[$arrayName][$value] = 1;
        }else{
            $resultArray[$arrayName][$value]++;
        }
    }
    arsort($resultArray[$arrayName]);
}

var_dump($resultArray);
```

**Edit:** AbraCadaver solution is much better, use this one. I will let the answer stay here anyway.