# how to get count of same values from multi dimension arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

**This is my database table**

[image]

**i am exploding these values like this**

```
<?php 
    $i =0;  
    foreach($appointment as $app_book){ 
       $arr[$i] = explode(",",$app_book['type_of_ultra_sound']); 
       $i++;
    } 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**output is this**

[image]

i tried this

```
$occurences = array_count_values($items);
print_r($occurences);
```

also i tried this but not help 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740079/php-count-same-values-in-multidimensional-array)

what i need is count of overall arrays similar values like 
**Doppler (Arm Arteries) = 2 ...**

Comment: Show us what you have tried. - Why didn't your own attempts work / what errors did you get?

Comment: question updated please check

Comment: Thats a HORRIBLE way of coding PHP. You only need to start and stop the PHP interpreter when necessary. NOT on every line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store values one by one in an array rather than creating multi dimensional array.

```
<?php
$i =0;
$arr = array();
foreach($appointment as $app_book) {
    $exp = explode(",",$app_book['type_of_ultra_sound']);
    foreach($exp as $v)
    {
        $arr[$i] = $v;
        $i++;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';

$occurences = array_count_values($arr);
print_r($occurences);

foreach($occurences as $keys => $values){
 echo $keys ." ". $values ."<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: oops this is same my code just with new variable. Thanks samir but i need result in variables. please guide further so i accept your answer thanks.

Comment: So you need count only for specific value. for e,g. Doppler (Arm Arteries) = 2 ?

Comment: thanks i edite your answer and added what i was asking. thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = [];
foreach($array as $s) {
    foreach($s as $ss) {
        if (!isset($values[$ss])) {
            $values[$ss]= 0;
        }
        $values[$ss]++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing a `)` in your if clause ;)

Comment: @Epodax Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested loop would suffice in your case:

```
// $arr is your array
$counts = array();
foreach($arr as $suba) {
    foreach($suba as $doppler) {
        (isset($counts[$doppler])) || $counts[$doppler] = 0;
         $counts[$doppler] += 1;
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
[25] boris> $arr;
// array(
//   0 => array(
//     0 => 'doppler a',
//     1 => 'doppler b'
//   ),
//   1 => array(
//     0 => 'doppler c',
//     1 => 'doppler b'
//   ),
//   2 => array(
//     0 => 'doppler a',
//     1 => 'doppler b',
//     2 => 'doppler c',
//     3 => 'doppler d'
//   )
// )
[26] boris> $counts = array();
// array(
//   
// )
[27] boris> foreach($arr as $suba) {
[27]     *>     foreach($suba as $doppler) {
[27]     *>         (isset($counts[$doppler])) || $counts[$doppler] = 0;
[27]     *>         $counts[$doppler] += 1;
[27]     *>     }
[27]     *> }
[28] boris> $counts;
// array(
//   'doppler a' => 2,
//   'doppler b' => 3,
//   'doppler c' => 2,
//   'doppler d' => 1
// )
[29] boris>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the separate "groups" you can flatten the array e.g. with

```
$usounds = [];
foreach($appointment as $app_book) { 
    $usounds = array_merge(
        $usounds,
        explode(',', $app_book['type_of_ultra_sound'])
    );
}
```

and then you can use [array_count_values](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

self-contained example:

```
<?php
$appointment = [
    [ 'type_of_ultra_sound'=>'Doppler (Arm Ateries),Doppler (Both Limbs)' ],
    [ 'type_of_ultra_sound'=>'Doppler (Arm Veins),Doppler (Liver)' ],
    [ 'type_of_ultra_sound'=>'Doppler (Arm Ateries),Doppler (Arm Veins),Doppler (Both Legs),Doppler (Both Limbs)' ]
];
$usounds = [];
foreach($appointment as $app_book) { 
    $usounds = array_merge(
        $usounds,
        explode(',', $app_book['type_of_ultra_sound'])
    );
}

var_export( array_count_values($usounds) );
```

prints

```
array (
  'Doppler (Arm Ateries)' => 2,
  'Doppler (Both Limbs)' => 2,
  'Doppler (Arm Veins)' => 2,
  'Doppler (Liver)' => 1,
  'Doppler (Both Legs)' => 1,
)
```

Comment: `array_merge` is a good solution but will have performance impact in case of large array since every time it will keep merging values of an array.

Comment: I think before reaching array sizes where that matters the database should be re-structured so that `type_of_ultra_sound` stores what the name implies - a singluar item. ;-)

Comment: Agree. Normalizing database should always be preferred :)